# sessionKey using nonce (client) and nonce(server) based on KDF2

Tags: asp.net, cryptography

I am working on a project. Client have common authentication system. I have to generate a nonce from my web server, encrypt using public key of authentication system, and sing using my webserver private key and post to the authentication system (XML base64 encoded). Authentication system decrypt using their private key, generate a nonce encrypt using my public key and and send back to my webserver in response. my webserver decrypt the response using my private key. 
Now next step is to construct a sessionKey using nonce (client) and nonce(server) based on KDF2 algorithm. I am using asp.net 4.0 .. not able to understand and find any kind of help on **"sessionKey using nonce (client) and nonce(server) based on KDF2 "**  in asp.net.

```
    protected void ButtonLogin_Click()
    {
        string datatopost = CreatEncryptandSignXML();
        PostxmltoCommongateway(datatopost);
    }

    public string CreatEncryptandSignXML()
    {
        string ClientNonce = null;
        ClientNonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        Session["ClientNonce"] = ClientNonce;

        byte[] bytesToEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClientNonce);

        string encodednonce = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesToEncode);

        string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><root><LoginRequest>Nonce=" + encodednonce + "</LoginRequest></root>";
        System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;

        // Sing XML using private key ------------------------------------------------------------
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 commonauthpublickey =
            new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
                (@"C:\commonauthserver\publickey\sample.cer");

        System.Xml.XmlElement elementToEncrypt = doc.GetElementsByTagName("LoginRequest")[0] as System.Xml.XmlElement;

        System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml encXML = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml();
        System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedData data = encXML.Encrypt(elementToEncrypt, commonauthpublickey);

        System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, data, false);


        // Sign XML using Private Key ---------------------------------------------------------------

        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 mywerbserverprivatekey =
            new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
                (@"C:\mywebserver\privatekey\mywebserver.pfx","samplepasword");

        System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml sign = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml(doc);

        System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.KeyInfo keyInfo = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.KeyInfo();
        sign.SigningKey = mywerbserverprivatekey.PrivateKey;
        System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoData = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.KeyInfoX509Data();
        keyInfoData.AddIssuerSerial(mywerbserverprivatekey.Issuer, mywerbserverprivatekey.GetSerialNumberString());
        keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData);
        sign.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
        System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference reference = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference();
        reference.Uri = "";
        System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new
            System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);
        sign.AddReference(reference);
        sign.ComputeSignature();
        System.Xml.XmlElement signedElement = sign.GetXml();
        signedElement.Prefix = "ds";
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(signedElement);
        return doc.InnerXml;
    }

    void PostxmltoCommongateway(string encData)
    {
        string URLAuth = "http://commonauth.com/getway/commomauth.do";

        byte[] bytesToEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encData);
        string encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesToEncode);
        string encodedXML = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encodedText);

        string postString = string.Format("encryptedData={0}", encodedXML);

        const string contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(URLAuth) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = contentType;
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
        webRequest.ContentLength = postString.Length;
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(postString);
        requestWriter.Close();

        try
        {
            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            responseReader.Close();
            webRequest.GetResponse().Close();

            string servernonce = DecryptResponse(responseData);
            string clientnonce = Session["ClientNonce"].ToString();

            /// here i have to generate a sessionKey using nonce (client) and nonce(server) based on KDF2

            // CreateSessionkeybasedonKDF2(servernonce,clientnonce)                
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LabelMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

public string DecryptResponse(string response)
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 mywerbserverprivatekey =
        new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
            (@"C:\mywebserver\privatekey\mywebserver.pfx", "samplepasword");

    RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = false;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)mywerbserverprivatekey.PrivateKey;
    byte[] decrypted = rsa.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(response), false);
    return ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);

}
```

Thank you for your response in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far? This sounds very much like a "here is my problem, please give me code" question, which is not permitted on StackOverflow. Perhaps you can post your current code?

Comment: Sorry Suncan Jones, posted the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDF2 is the key seed (any length, should represent a key with enough entropy) postfixed by a 4 byte counter value in BigEndian notation, starting with value 1. So that would be `KEY_SEED|00000001` for the first key. After the concatenation the value is hashed using a secure hash algorithm like SHA-1 (the hash to be used is configurable). Then you take the X *leftmost* bits or bytes you require from the resulting hash value.

I can only tell you how to implement KDF2 as it is not often included in cryptographic API's, I'm afraid you have to do the implementation and testing yourself (that's "too localized" anyway).

Comment: thank you for response can u share the logic or psudo code or any other programming language.  suppose my shared string is "ndjeucjMjduj346m" 16 byte string and my key derivation parameter is "3sksiskOPskw33id" again 16 byte string. I have to generate a 32 byte key using KDF2 algorithm.

Comment: Actual requirment is above code and then 
1.construct the sessionKey based on the
  generated nonce (client ,16 byte string ) and nonce (server ,16 byte string ) based on KDF2.

2. encrypt the target URL (e.g. "http://mywebserver.com/pages/default.aspx")  with the generated
   sessionKey using AES encryption algorithm and concatenate it with the
  HMAC (SHA-1 with AES-256-CBC) of the encrypted parameter.

Comment: @user2077725 I cannot give you the code because you need to know how to use the given data as the seed. Furthermore, you need to know which hash function to use. SHA-256 is likely (as it outputs 256 bits) but other hash functions are possible as well.

Comment: Start with retrieving and reading the standards, and retrieving all information possible from the other party. Then you can try out things and ask more specific questions here.